# Find elements up to a certain point

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have an XPath problem. I need a test condition for any `<iframe>` that is included in a `<part>`, but not any `<iframe>`s that are included in a `<chapter>`. Note that `<chapter>`s are included in a `<part>`.

XML:

```
<book>
<part id="p1">
    <h1>Add a heading</h1>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>more text here</p>
    <div>
        <h2>Add another heading</h2>
        <p>more text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="someDivision">
        <div class="someOtherDivision">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <div class="sect">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <iframe>Add iframe content</iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <chapter>
        <h1>Add a chapter heading</h1>
        <p>some chapter text here</p>
        <div class="someDivision">
            <div class="someOtherDivision">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <div class="sect">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <iframe>Add more iframe content</iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </chapter>
</part>
<part id="p2">
    <h1>Add a heading</h1>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>more text here</p>
    <div>
        <h2>Add another heading</h2>
        <p>more text</p>
    </div>
    <chapter>
        <h1>Add a chapter heading</h1>
        <p>some chapter text here</p>
        <div class="someDivision">
            <div class="someOtherDivision">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <div class="sect">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <iframe>Add more iframe content</iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </chapter>
</part>
</book>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="manifest">
            <xsl:for-each select="//part">
                <xsl:element name="item">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id" select="@id/string()"/>
                    <xsl:if test="//div[@class='someDivision']/div[@class='someOtherDivision']//iframe">
                        <xsl:attribute name="properties" select="'remote-resources'"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

I get this result:

```
<manifest>
    <item id="p1" properties="remote-resources"/>
    <item id="p2" properties="remote-resources"/>
</manifest>
```

But I only want:

```
<manifest>
    <item id="p1" properties="remote-resources"/>
</manifest>
```

As there is no `<iframe>` directly in `<part>` and not nested within a `<chapter>`. But I'm not sure how to accomplish this when my XPath will select any `<iframe>` within a `<part>` (which includes the ones in a `<chapter>`.

Comment: You ask about selecting `iframe`s, but your XSLT selects `part`s?

Comment: I should change that to "test" condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to select any `<iframe>` that is included in a `<part>`, but not any `<iframe>`s that are included in a `<chapter>`.

So how about:

```
/book/part//iframe[not(ancestor::chapter)]
```

---

### Added:

If you want to test, from the context of a `part`, if the current `part` contains any `iframe` elements that are not descendants of a `chapter`, then do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/book">
    <manifest>
        <xsl:for-each select="part">
            <item id="{@id}">
                <xsl:if test=".//iframe[not(ancestor::chapter)]">
                    <!-- code if true -->
                </xsl:if>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </manifest>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/jyH9rLY

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't get me my expected output. I still get both <item> elements.

Comment: Sorry, what  `<item>` elements are you referring to? Did you mean `<iframe>` elements?

Comment: If you did mean `item` elements, you are getting two because there are two `part` elements in your input; your test comes **after** you create the  item`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant two items with the properties="remote-resources". This new option of .//iframe[not(ancestor::chapter)] does the trick though! Many thanks!